# TCP delimited Datagram concatenation with Netty

Tags: netty

Having some challenge understanding the layers.
I have multiple clients connecting to a server.
Each client sends short datagrams terminated by `'\r\n'` but the server processing should not start unless a final DELIMITER arrives (concatenate the chunks per connection).

1. Do I extend the `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder`
2. Should I add a child pipeline and concatenate the string (this is easier)? But how to preserve the previous chunks in the `ChannelHandlerAdapter`?

To clarify the challenge: I am trying to avoid having to maintain the state (previous chunks).

Any sample or suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case, under the `Datagram` you mean message from the client without terminating delimeter - than `DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder` would be totally fine. You also don't have to extend it. You need just to add it to the pipeline and in the next handler after it - you'll receive `ByteBuf` that is ready (accumulated) frame (all data that was sent by the client before terminating delimiter).

```
pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(65536, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
pipeline.addLast(new MyHandler());

class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {
    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
       //msg is accumulated frames from your client, before terminating delimiter
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitry!, on the same note, is there a way to save session data? Assume during authentication the code fetches some metadata from the database that I want to reuse on every new message, where can I add a property bad that carries forward with ctx on every channelRead ?

Comment: @UriKluk sure. You need to use `ctx.channel().attr()` in that case or as alternative some concurrent map. It is up to you. Netty attributes, however, are easier way.